# How to check for presence of a login in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I use an ASP.NET Web API. How do I check my login with a `Post` request? I want to check if the login already exists in the database, and if so, throw an error.

`UsersController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
{
    if (_context.Users == null)
    {
        return Problem("Entity set 'ShopContext.Users'  is null.");
    }

    var role = await _context.Roles.FindAsync(user.IdRole);

    if (role == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < user.Id; i++)
    {
        if (i == user.UserName.Length)
        {
            return Problem("User already registered");
        }
    }

    user.Role = role;

    _context.Users.Add(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
}
```

`User` model:

```
namespace ShopAPI.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: My cycle is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
    {

      var userWithIdAlreadyExists = _context.Users.Find(user.Id) != null;
      if(userAlreadyExists)
      {
          return Problem ("user with id already exists");
      }
      
      var userNameAlreadyExists = _context.users
      .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName) == null;
      if(userNameAlreadyExists)  
      {
          return Problem("User already exists with that name");
      }

      //Write the code you want to execute when the user has a valid id and username 
   
    }
```

Comment: if(userNameAlreadyExists)  ERROR

Comment: @G-genius , that line needs to check for null as it's not a bool type. Try using this to check if it's null, if it isn't then the user already exists, if it is then the user doesn't already exist...... `if(userNameAlreadyExists != null)  { return Problem("User already exists with that name"); }`

Comment: @teslae In my comment I'm referring to the variable named, `userNameAlreadyExists`, not the one you posted in your reply comment which is, `userWithIdAlreadyExists` (can you spot the difference!). [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0) will return the `default` value if it doesn't find a match, in this case the default value for the `User` class is in fact `null`. Good luck.